# Get all test cases and test steps in SoapUI-project

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm looking for a way to get all the test cases with belonging test steps in SoapUI Pro.

I've managed to get all the test steps under one test case (Groovy in Setup Script)

```
def projectName= testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getName()   
def testcaseName = testRunner.getTestCase().getName()   

File myTestFile = new File("C:/temp/" + projectName + ".txt")

myTestFile .withWriterAppend{ out ->

            out.println("TestCase: " + testcaseName)
                testRunner.testCase.getTestStepList().each(){
                    out.println("TestStep: " + it.getName())

    }



}
```

How can I get all test cases and test steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you:

```
for ( testSuite in testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteList() ) {
    for ( testCase in testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseList() ) {
        for ( testStep in testCase.getTestStepList() ) {
            log.info "${testSuite.getName()} : ${testCase.getName()} : ${testStep.getName()} is a test step of type: ${testStep.getClass().toString().tokenize('.')[-1]}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did put your code in Project (root) --> "Setup Script" and pressed "Run this script" and got: Error: com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.ScriptingException: Error in Setup Script of MyTestProject

Comment: @user3624378 it is an example of how to access the elements. Adapt your code to include what you need. I can run it anywhere in my SoapUI and it works.

Comment: Works lika a charm :-) Thanks a lot for your solution.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment (<50 reputation) or Edit (edit queue is full) on [ou_ryperd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60075519/4688118), but I put here a little change to anyone else that will use his code.

If the code is executed within a case context, the 2nd *for* called always the current TestSuite. Call the TestSuite from the 1st *for* instead, this way:

```
for ( testSuite in testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteList() ) {
    for ( testCase in testSuite.getTestCaseList() ) {
        for ( testStep in testCase.getTestStepList() ) {
            log.info "${testSuite.getName()} : ${testCase.getName()} : ${testStep.getName()} is a test step of type: ${testStep.getClass().toString().tokenize('.')[-1]}"
        }
    }
}
```

All credits to [ou_ryperd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3355860/ou-ryperd).